# Setting custom alarm tone in android

Tags: android, alarm

Hello I wonder how to set a custom alarm tone.

This is my code:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    this,
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM,
                    newUri
                    );
```

It is working for notications / sounds but not for alarms ( :S ) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```
Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
 if(alert == null){
     // alert is null, using backup
     alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
     if(alert == null){  // I can't see this ever being null (as always have a default notification) but just incase
         // alert backup is null, using 2nd backup
         alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);               
     }
 }
```

Comment: I found that code to on the internet but it's not working either.

Comment: The set alarm tone method above is working but you need to make a new alarm if you want to use the tone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
  playRingtone(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), ringtoneUri));
```

And then, write another method **playRingtone(Ringtone newRingtone)** to play the ringtone.

```
private void playRingtone(Ringtone newRingtone) {

        if(null != mCurrentRingtone && mCurrentRingtone.isPlaying())
            mCurrentRingtone.stop();

            mCurrentRingtone = newRingtone;

        if(null != newRingtone){
            mCurrentRingtone.play();
        }
    }
```